# How to maximize function $\sum_{i=1}^{\omega}\max(0, \log(x_i))$ under the constraint that $\sum_{i=1}^{\omega}x_i = S$

Tags: inequality, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I am trying to maximize this function: $\sum_{i=1}^{\omega}\max(0, \log(x_i))$ given the constraint that $\sum_{i=1}^{\omega}x_i = S$.

If the function was just $\sum_{i=1}^{\omega}\log(x_i)$ I could just use Jensen's inequality and say that the maximum value is when each $x_i = \frac{S}{\omega}$ and so maximum value is $\sum_{i=1}^{\omega}\log(\frac{S}{\omega}) = \omega\log(\frac{S}{\omega})$.

Alternatively I could use Lagrange multipliers and derive the same outcome.

But in my case max function introduces non-continuity at i's where $x_i = 1$, so I suppose Lagrange multipliers is not applicable here...

I would like at least to find an upper bound of the sum I gave, as tight as possible under the constraint I gave, if it's not possible to derive the maximum value

Answer (score 0):

Is $x_i$ allowed to be negative?

The optimal value will not have any $x_i \leq 1$, so you can add in another constraint $x_i \geq 1$.

Your problem is now $max(\sum log(x_i) : x_i \geq 1, \sum x_i = S)$. The objective function is now continuous in $x_i$, and you can use something like KKT conditions or steepest descent (or ascent in this case) to find the optimal value.

Comment: $x_i$ is not allowed to be negative. In general $0 \leq x_i \leq S$. So $x_i$ can have values less than 1

Comment: If $x_i < 1$, then you can set it to 0 and thus remove it from the problem.

Comment: The problem in that case is I don't know how many of $x_i$'s  are <1 . So I don't know in the new problem the limits of the sum

Comment: if I don't know the sum limits in the constraint $\sum x_i = S$ then I cannot calculate the lagrange-KKT mutlipliers

Comment: I would just guess. Any non-zero element must satisfy $x_i \geq 1$ (otherwise you can make the objective higher by setting $x_i = 0$ and increasing another variable by $x_i$).

Only finitely many possibilities : $floor(S)$ to be exact

Comment: I agree that any non-zero element should be $\geq 1$. The finite possibilities you refer actually are infeasible  The possible ways to distribute S-units to at most $\omega$ positions is equivalent to assign each unit (among S) a tag with value in $[1, \omega]$. That is at most $\omega^S$ different possibilities. How come to be just floor(S)?. In any case it resembles the process like brute force without any short route to the maximum